# iOS Crash Core Location CFBasicHashCreateCopy?

Tags: ios, crash, core-location, core-foundation

I've got this issue being reported via Crashlytics, although I've been unable to replicate it locally, so I've got nothing to go on other than the stack trace below.. Not sure if the references to CoreLocation in the stack trace have anything to do with it, but I'm not sure what could possibly be the cause. My project is using ARC. Any clue?

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x14eb3510.events
0  CoreFoundation                 0x307769a8 CFBasicHashCreateCopy + 712
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3afd1a19 object_setClass + 24
2  CoreFoundation                 0x30782d0f CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy + 154
3  CoreLocation                   0x30d0a8f3 CLLocationCoordinate2DGetDistanceFrom + 47590
4  CoreLocation                   0x30d2d607 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 49626
5  CoreFoundation                 0x30786d45 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 16
6  CoreFoundation                 0x30772cd4 CFBasicHashApply + 128
7  CoreFoundation                 0x3077be27 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 154
8  CoreLocation                   0x30d2cc25 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 47096
9  CoreLocation                   0x30d2b625 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 41464
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x3b5fc3a9 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 40
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x3b5fee67 do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 122
12 libxpc.dylib                   0x3b5fedd1 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 104
13 libxpc.dylib                   0x3b5fed47 notify_server + 62
14 libxpc.dylib                   0x3b5fa9cf _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1926
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4bdf43 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 118
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4c0c71 _dispatch_queue_drain + 412
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4bda6b _dispatch_mach_invoke + 78
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4c0c71 _dispatch_queue_drain + 412
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4bdc6f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4c0c71 _dispatch_queue_drain + 412
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4bdc6f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4c15f1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x3b4c18dd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
24 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x3b5ecc17 _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

Here is another, likely related.

```
Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x17665330.events
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x11755e44

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x17665330.events
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x381db626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreFoundation                 0x2d979d75 CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy + 320
2  CoreLocation                   0x2df018f3 (null) + 47590
3  CoreLocation                   0x2df24607 (null) + 49626
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2d97dd05 __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 16
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2d969c94 CFBasicHashApply + 128
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2d972de7 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 154
7  CoreLocation                   0x2df23c25 (null) + 47096
8  CoreLocation                   0x2df22625 (null) + 41464
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x387fb3a9 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 40
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x387fde67 do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 122
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x387fddd1 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 104
12 libxpc.dylib                   0x387fdd47 notify_server + 62
13 libxpc.dylib                   0x387f99cf _xpc_connection_mach_event + 1926
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x386bcf43 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 118
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x386bfc71 _dispatch_queue_drain + 412
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x386bca6b _dispatch_mach_invoke + 78
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x386bfc71 _dispatch_queue_drain + 412
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x386bcc6f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x386bfc71 _dispatch_queue_drain + 412
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x386bcc6f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x386c05f1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x386c08dd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
23 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x387ebc17 _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

Comment: I've exactly the same issue and really can't find the problem, did you finally find the source?

Comment: Unfortunately never did.

Answer (score 2):

You've had the system send a message to a bad memory location where an object should have been.  So my suggestion is to enable zombie detection (Edit Scheme, then select the Diagnostics Tab, tick enable zombie objects) and re-do your test scenarios in particular anything that causes CoreLocation events.

Then when core location sends a message to a released object, you will know what the object was originally that got released (because it is artificially kept alive by this debug setting as a zombie object).

Comment: That would be easy to do, the problem here unfortunately is it is an uncommon bug that I've only ever seen via crashlytics in a release build with tens of thousands of users. I've never been able to replicate it locally.

Comment: Fair enough.  Although not an easy road, one approach is to make the problem appear more frequently.  Essentially you set breakpoints in your code due to CoreLocation events and try out use cases to find which ones can trigger them, e.g. disabling the location tracking for the app, or maybe just backgrounding/foregrounding, etc.  Then write test code which repeats these steps automatically and then get it to run repeatedly and in different combinations.  Making a problem more exposed can give insights and can provide run-time data to solve the issue.

Comment: Do you think this has to do with a mutable dictionary?

Comment: Mutability is a key aspect of your code to validate so you could be on the right track. Re-using or re-purposing objects passed in to a dictionary, or changing the dictionary before a callback which uses the dictionary can cause Invariance problems (things which are suppose to hold true but don't).  Lifetime is another issue; is the life of any object managed disjointly to when is it being used so it could be end of life, and then used.

Comment: I'm only using a single mutable dictionary in my project, and it's totally unrelated to core location stuff completely. I suppose I'll have to dig into it more and see what's going on. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @Mike, did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.

Comment: For what it is worth, I am seeing the same thing on my project via Crashlytics.  it only impacts a very small percentage of users and doesn't seem to happen more than once per user.... Apple bug?