# iOS 9 core location crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, core-location

I'm unable to find out the reason for the crash for the reason `CLClientCreateIso6709Notation`.

This is mentioned in [here](http://www.openradar.me/15464668),[here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9105),[here](http://technology.ezeenow.com/posts/102925/CoreLocation_thread_crash_Crashed_com_apple_CoreLocation_ConnectionClient_0x16fcb870_events) and in [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271393/ios-crash-core-location-cfbasichashcreatecopy), but they are bit different than this one.

The stacktrace returned by Crashlytics is:

```
Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x156c4f1a0.events
0  CoreLocation                   0x1896c4a20 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 51884
1  CoreLocation                   0x1896c4cc8 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 52564
2  CoreLocation                   0x1896c4c0c CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 52376
3  CoreLocation                   0x1896c7a10 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 64156
4  CoreLocation                   0x1896c6ec4 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 61264
5  CoreLocation                   0x1896c5a60 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 56044
6  libxpc.dylib                   0x1825c8f68 _xpc_connection_call_event_handler + 68
7  libxpc.dylib                   0x1825ccdf0 do_mach_notify_port_destroyed + 124
8  libxpc.dylib                   0x1825ccd40 _Xmach_notify_port_destroyed + 80
9  libxpc.dylib                   0x1825cccc4 notify_server + 100
10 libxpc.dylib                   0x1825c6cd8 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 2076
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x18237d578 _dispatch_client_callout4 + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x182381864 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 656
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x182389694 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x182380978 _dispatch_mach_invoke + 600
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x182389694 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x182380f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x182389694 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1332
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x182380f80 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x18238b390 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 728
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x18238b0b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
21 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182595470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
22 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x182595020 start_wqthread + 4
```

The zombie instrument didn't show any issue for my device.I'm using iphone 5s, and the crash seemed to happen on iphone 6.

I have no idea if this is an issue with apple OS/googlemaps.

This is how I initialize my location manager class:

```
 @property (strong,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

-(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
            self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            self.locationManager.delegate = self;
            self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 1;
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
            self.buildings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
    return self;
}

 + (id)sharedInstance {
    static LocationMonitor *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
 }

- (void)requestAuthorization {

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}
```

and in my Vc viewDidLoad:

```
  [[LocationMonitor sharedInstance] requestAuthorization];
```

and in my plist I have `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` but not `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`

Any ideas?

Comment: and where do you Requesting Permission to Use Location Services? Like `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization`? Do you have in your plist `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`?

Comment: updated my question.@TonyMkenu

Comment: seems ok... clear it's a crashes in the internals of CoreLocation. I've seen this error, but very rarely ... can be an Apple bug :)

Comment: usually occurs if you have multiple `CLLocationManager` instances, or... you are calling many times and very quickly `startUpdatingLocation` and 'stopUpdatingLocation`...

Comment: I think this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38237841/corelocation-thread-crash-crashed-com-apple-corelocation-connectionclient-0x16f) might help.